# Reserved EventIds in ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I am creating some LogError calls in my ASP.NET Core webapp on the line of

```
_logger.LogError(new EventId(5000,"CustomName"),"description");``
```

I can find this event in Application Insights by querying like this

```
traces | where timestamp > ago(10m) |where customDimensions.EventId == 5000
```

Is there any list of event ids that is reserved? I only want to get my own events. I know that a third party library that i bind to my project theoretically can write some events with the above event id, but I am thinking more if Microsoft has a list of reserved event ids. If I do this search in my log

```
traces | where timestamp > ago(10m) |where customDimensions.EventId > 1
```

I get some hits, on Azure Function startup, so I know that Microsoft are using this also.

I have searched the docs, but haven't found any list.

Comment: there are no reserve ids as far as i know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there're no reserved EventIDs in app insights. You always need to provide it by yourself.